# "OpenGL version is too low (0)" does this matter with a remote connection?

Tags: x11, remote, opengl, mesa

I'm running an app on a remote Linux machine, whose console output tells me:

```
OpenGL version is too low (0). Falling back to Mesa software rendering.
OpenGL version: "3.1 Mesa 18.1.9 (git-f57f37f3ba)"
```

Now, this is an old machine, so I wouldn't be surprised if the app found something to be too low. However - it's a remote connection. Does it even matter that the OpenGL version is low? Would there be any benefit for using it in my case?

PS - This is a CentOS 7 machine :-(  , with some NVIDIA cards used for compute, not graphics. If any additional information is required, please comment and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

> However - it's a remote connection.

So I am assuming `ssh -X` or similar.

> Does it even matter that the OpenGL version is low? Would there be any benefit for using it in my case?

No, you need special protocols for OpenGL acceleration over a remote connection. So it normally falls back to software rendering anyhow.

> with some NVIDIA cards used for compute, not graphics

Which means you cannot use the NVIDIA cards for compute via the remote connection, either.

Comment: So, the bottom-line answer is "No"...

Comment: Well, you *could* use something like virtualgl if it's important to you, but then you need to make changes to the old machine.